API Response models used in Swagger to extend from Dynamoose Item class?
I'm working on a project where I'm using the same model for both API response documentation (with @nestjs/swagger's ApiProperty decorator) and data access (with Dynamoose in my NestJS project). Currently, my response model for ProductRequest looks like this:
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class ProductRequest {
  @ApiProperty()
  Id: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  IdUser: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  IdProductRequestType: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  Industry: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  Status: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  CreatedAt: number;

  @ApiProperty()
  Quotes: []; // Empty array initially, filled later when companies add quotes
}

In my data access layer, I’m using Dynamoose, and the model has to extend from dynamoose.Item in order to match with a schema. However, I feel that forcing the API response model to inherit from dynamoose.Item isn’t the best approach because these models serve different purposes.Is having my api response models extend and connect directly to the data acess logic by extending them from Item class? Any ideas? I also don't want to have duplicated layers of pretty much same classes
